# Div scolling with scrollview plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jquerymobile, and i want to scroll my each div individually, something like :

```
   <div data-role="content">
    <div id="1"></div>
    <div id="2"></div>
   </div>
```

Now i want that, `div#1 scroll left - right`  &  `div#2 scroll top - bottom` . I am using scrollview plugin but i am not able to do this. Can anybody help me out with a little example code?

Comment: Asking for example code is generally a mistake here.  You're better off asking for suggestions or explanations in cases like this.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using this with the experimental jQuery Mobile scrollview.

You can set a value for the data-scroll attribute as `data-scroll="y"` or `data-scroll="x"` to set the scrolling direction as vertical or horizontal.